# Distance between two points using CLLocation varies although device is not moving

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocation

I read the latitude and the longitude of the QR code as those information are inside the QR code like so :

```
class ScannedQRCode {
    let issuer : String
    let eventName : String
    let eventCode : String
    let issuedYear : Int
    let issuedMonth : Int
    let issuedDay : Int
    let issuedHour : Int
    let issuedMin : Int
    let locatoin : CLLocation



    init(issuer : String , eventName : String , eventCode : String , issuedYear : Int ,issuedMonth : Int ,  issuedDay : Int , issuedHour : Int , issuedMin : Int , lat : Double , long : Double) {
        self.issuer = issuer
        self.eventName = eventName
        self.eventCode = eventCode
        self.issuedYear = issuedYear
        self.issuedMonth = issuedMonth
        self.issuedDay = issuedDay
        self.issuedHour = issuedHour
        self.issuedMin = issuedMin
        self.locatoin = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    }



    public func getIssuer () -> String {return self.issuer}
    public func getEventName () -> String {return self.eventName}
    public func getEventCode () -> String {return self.eventCode}
    public func getIssuedYear () -> Int {return self.issuedYear}
    public func getIssuedMonth () -> Int {return self.issuedMonth}
    public func getIssuedDay () -> Int {return self.issuedDay}
    public func getIssuedHour () -> Int {return self.issuedHour}
    public func getIssuedMin () -> Int {return self.issuedMin}
    public func getLocatoin () -> CLLocation {return self.locatoin}




    public func getDescription () -> String {
        return ("The given QR code is generated by \(self.getIssuer()) on the year  \(self.getIssuedYear()) and month \(self.getIssuedMonth()) and day \(self.getIssuedDay()) and hour \(self.getIssuedHour()) and minutes \(self.getIssuedMin()) and for an event called \(self.getEventName()) and having the code \(self.getEventCode()) for the following location lat: \(self.getLocatoin().coordinate.latitude) and Long : \(self.getLocatoin().coordinate.longitude)")

    }


    func validateLocatoin () -> Bool{
        var validation = false


        let Mylocation = CLLocation(latitude: myLocation().latitude, longitude: myLocation().longitude)
        let distance = calculateDistance(LocationA: self.getLocatoin() , LocationB: Mylocation )
        print("The distance is : \(distance)")
        if (distance < 20 ) {

            validation = true
        }


        return validation
    }




    func validateTime () -> Bool {
        var validation = false


        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour ,.minute], from: date)

         let year =  (components.year)!
         let month = (components.month)!
         let day =  (components.day)!
         let hour = (components.hour)!
         let min =  (components.minute)!




        if (self.getIssuedYear() == year  && self.getIssuedMonth() == month && self.getIssuedDay() == day && self.getIssuedHour() == hour ){
            if (min - self.getIssuedMin() < 15){
                    validation = true
            }
        }


        return validation
    }

}
```

And also I have created another function called myLocation as follows :

```
public func myLocation () -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    var currentLocation: CLLocation!
    var locManager = CLLocationManager()
    locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if ( CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedAlways || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .authorizedWhenInUse )  {
    currentLocation = locManager.location

    }else {
        myLocation()
    }

    return currentLocation.coordinate

}
```

And here is my code for calculating the distance of two points :

```
public func calculateDistance (LocationA : CLLocation , LocationB : CLLocation) -> Double{
    let distanceInMeters = LocationA.distance(from: LocationB)
    return distanceInMeters
}
```

And I call them like so :

```
let attendance = ScannedQRCode(issuer: String(scannedCode[0]),
                                       eventName:String(scannedCode[1]) ,
                                       eventCode: String(scannedCode[2]),
                                       issuedYear: Int(scannedCode[3])!,
                                       issuedMonth: Int(scannedCode[4])!,
                                       issuedDay: Int(scannedCode[5])!,
                                       issuedHour: Int(scannedCode[6])!,
                                       issuedMin: Int(scannedCode[7])!,
                                       lat: Double(scannedCode[8])!,
                                       long: Double(scannedCode[9])!
        )
```

and then when I call the validateLocation it gives me different results even though I am not moving at all. Any idea where am I making my mistake ?

When I print the distance I get `The distance is : 3.63338273593823e-08` and I have only moved my hands. According to the other questions on stack overflow this value is measured in meter and it doesnt make sense ?

Comment: 3.63338273593823e-08 meters is 0.0000363 millimeters.  This is probably within the accuracy of GPS and equivalent to 0 (not moving at all)

Comment: @LouFranco .   Yes I agree with you. But the problem is in my validateLocatoin function when I set the distance to be less than 20 meters like `distance < 20 ` it returns false even though 20 > 21.63338273593823e-08
right ?

Comment: Your code has bigger problems. Your `myLocation` function doesn't really get the user's current location properly.

Comment: @rmaddy oh why is that so ?

Comment: Find a good tutorial on using core location. You need to properly create and setup a single instance of CLLocationMananager, implement appropriate delegate methods, and start location updates.

Comment: @rmaddy alright, thanks for your comment. But let me ask you a question for the learning purpose. so the coordinations that i get using myLocation function are not the most updated ones ?

Comment: Probably not. Check the location's timestamp and accuracy values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167949/discussion-between-danial-kosarifa-and-rmaddy).

Comment: How do you know that validateLocatoin returns false when `distance < 20`? I think you are mistaken -- the best way is to set a break point and follow in the debugger. Or put another print right before the return with the distance and the validation variable.  Also, what does validation mean to you? Why is distance < 20 valid and other distances are not?